# Achart engine, chart inside another chart

Tags: java, android

I tried to draw a bar chart which displays with a click on a pie chart.but it gives me errors. can i draw a bar chart for a click event on another pie chart using Achartengine in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got two useful links and able to solve my problem. They are below...

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-pie-chart-with-click-event-in-a-custom-xml-layout-using-achartengine/

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-drawing-bar-chart-using-achartengine/

Thank You!